# IE8 not loading stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Hi I seem to be having a problem with IE8 loading the stylesheet everything works well in IE9
but when I try it on IEteste it looks like it didn't load the stylesheet.Here is the links to the website:

[website link](http://www.nistoralexandru.comule.com/articles.html)

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a script tag for analytical purposes placed outside of the HTML tag. It needs to ideally be within the BODY tags. This is throwing a HTML validation error. That could be the cause of it.

**Edit:**

As someone mentioned, you might need some additional JavaScript to get IE < 9 working with HTML5 elements (tags). IE in versions lower than 9 don't understand many of these tags, so applying styles to them will do nothing. It simply fails silently.

Check this page for the code and information about this:
http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/

Once applying your CSS, you may also need to style many of these elements with `display: block` as many are inline by default.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be including the html5 javascript shiv for older browsers:

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

I'd also move that trailing script inside the /body tag.